# How many rotations or degrees do I need to turn my robot?

Tags: ev3

I have an EV3 Home edition. I have made a tribot. It has two main motors for the wheels and a caster in the back. To complete a full turn in place I need to set the rotations to 2.32 or 835 degrees.

[image]

Does this seem normal to you? I am using *The Art of Lego Mindstorms EV3 Programming.* The author gets his tribot to turn one full turn in place by setting the degrees to 425. I am just curious about why my setting is almost double. We are both using home editions.

Comment: Actually I have answered my own question.  425 is for a 180 degree turn.  Doh!

Comment: Glad you figured it out yourself! But just for future reference, it's actually very easy to calculate how many wheel degrees you need for any robot rotation. See [this post here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/10482/6720).

Comment: Also, the distance between the two driving wheels and the speed used can affect how many degrees are required for turning. For example, you may think that turning 90° will make your robot make a perfect turn to the right. That's wrong! It really depends on the design of the robot and the amount of speed used!